# Duplicate names showing when joining tables from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in my database. One is a schedules table and the other is a league teams table. The schedules table does not have the names of the teams, it just has their ID, but the teams table does.

[My tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5V1c.jpg)

I used this code to JOIN the tables

```
SELECT statsSchedules.*
     , leagueTeams.logoId
     , leagueTeams.cityName
     , leagueTeams.displayName 
FROM statsSchedules 
JOIN leagueTeams 
WHERE statsSchedules.homeTeamId 
  AND statsSchedules.awayTeamId=leagueTeams.teamId 
ORDER BY statsSchedules.weekIndex ASC
```

As you can see on this page http://2kolf.com/our-data/schedules-test.php the away teams (on the left) are correct but the name for the home teams are the same as the away team.

I've tried changing my code to this -

```
SELECT statsSchedules.*
     , leagueTeams.logoId
     , leagueTeams.cityName
     , leagueTeams.displayName 
FROM statsSchedules 
JOIN leagueTeams 
WHERE statsSchedules.homeTeamId=leagueTeams.teamId 
  AND statsSchedules.awayTeamId=leagueTeams.teamId 
ORDER BY statsSchedules.weekIndex ASC
```

But that returns nothing.

Comment: You will want to use two joins: one for the away team and one for the home team. Currently you're joining just once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each unique Primary Key(PK) / Foreign Key (FK) relationship you have; a join is required.

Since statsSchedules has two FKs to leagueTeams, you need two leagueTeam Joins.

Since the column names would be the same, I recommend aliasing not only those; but the table join as well.

```
SELECT statsSchedules.*
     , homeTeam.logoId homeLogoId 
     , homeTeam.cityName homeCityName
     , homeTeam.displayName homeDisplayName
     , awayTeam.logoId awayLogoID
     , awayTeam.cityName awayCityName
     , awayTeam.displayName awayDisplayName
FROM statsSchedules 
INNER JOIN leagueTeams as homeTeam
   ON  statsSchedules.homeTeamId = homeTeam.TeamID
INNER JOIN leagueTeams as awayTeam 
   ON statsSchedules.awayTeamId = awayTeam.teamId 
ORDER BY statsSchedules.weekIndex ASC
```

Comment: That worked. At first I was not seeing the names then realized I had to change the away and home to awayCityName and homeCityname in my PHP. http://2kolf.com/our-data/schedules-test.php

Comment: Oi vey.  my camel case sucks; glad you figured it out :P

Answer (score 0):

if you have two tea  you need  two inner join between statsSchedules and leagueTeams

```
  SELECT 
        statsSchedules.*
      , a.logoId
      , a.cityName
      , a.displayName 
      , b.logoId
      , b.cityName
      , b.displayName     
  FROM statsSchedules 
  INNER JOIN leagueTeams a  ON  statsSchedules.homeTeamId = a.teamId
  INNER JOIN leagueTeams b  ON  statsSchedules.homeTeamId = b.teamId
  ORDER BY statsSchedules.weekIndex ASC
```